# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I got a problem with references. (object references an unsaved transient instance)

I just don't see the problem. Any idea?

So, this is what I would like to save:

---

```
public class ServerInfo : IPersistenzEntity {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Host { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ServerUptime> ServerUptime { get; set; }
}

public class ServerUptime : IPersistenzEntity {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    // public virtual ServerInfo Server { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

---

This is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uptime` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `startdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `enddate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `server_id` (`server_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

---

The mapping i used:

```
    public ServerInfoMap() {
        Table("server");
        // LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Host);

        HasMany(x => x.DriveInfos)
            .KeyColumn("server_id");
        HasMany(x => x.ServerUptime)
            .KeyColumn("server_id");
    }

    public ServerUptimeMap() {
        Table( "uptime" );
        // LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.Id);
        // References(x => x.Server).Column("server_id");

        Map(x => x.StartDate);
        Map(x => x.EndDate);
    }
```

---

And finally the configuration:

```
    public void Init(string connectionString) {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString)))
            // .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
            .Mappings(m => 
                    m.FluentMappings
                        .AddFromAssemblyOf<AppliciationSettings>()
                        .Conventions.Add(
                            PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "id"),
                            DefaultLazy.Always(),
                            ForeignKey.EndsWith("id")
                        )
                    )

            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }


    public void UpdateEntity(IPersistenzEntity entity) {
        // Initiate update time ...
        using (var session = Session.OpenSession()) {
            // populate the database
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) {
                session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Test() {
        ServerInfo serverInfo = new ServerInfo() {
            Host = "host",
            ServerUptime = new SuperObservableCollection<ServerUptime>(
            )
        };

        ServerUptime serverUptime = new ServerUptime() {
            // Server = serverInfo,
            StartDate = DateTime.Now,
            EndDate = DateTime.Now,
        };
        serverInfo.ServerUptime.Add(serverUptime);

        UpdateEntity(serverInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ServerInfo` has some new `ServerUptime` instances in his `ServerUptime` collection which have to be saved to update the reference to `ServerInfo` in them. USe Cascade.All to let the engine save new instance in `ServerUptime` collection automaticly

```
HasMany(x => x.ServerUptime).Cascade.All().KeyColumn("server_id");
```

Comment: Its great that this answer worked, but it would be more helpful to others if the answer said why to use Cascade.All to fix the issue.